# JQuery 2 Data Table use one page

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have two table in my page i got this data using Ajax. Now i want to add default contain like add button. When i click the button it will go with a id. But when i do that normally for one table its work. But when i use two table with different id its not work it id is not show accurately.

```
$(function () {
        var table = $('#example6').DataTable({
            'paging': true,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ url('/manage-order/data') }}",
                type: 'post'
            },

            "columns": [

                {"data": "vn_name"},
                {"data": "vn_id"},
                {"data": "total_payment_amount"},
                {"data": "total_due_ammont"},

                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<a id='addBtn' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' title='Add Purchase'>\n" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>\n" +
                    "</a>\n" 
                }
            ]
        });

        var table = $('#example5').DataTable({
            'paging': true,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ url('/manage-general-sales/data') }}",
                type: 'post'
            },
            "columns": [

                {"data": "vendor_name"},
                {"data": "total_payment_amount"},
                {"data": "total_due_amount"},
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<a id='addBtnGneral' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' title='Add Purchase'>\n" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>\n" +
                    "</a>\n" 
                }
            ]
        });
        $('#example6 tbody').on('click', '#addBtn', function () {
            var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var vn_id = data['vn_id'];
            var url = "{{url('/create-order/')}}/" + vn_id;
            window.location.href = url;
        });


        $('#example5 tbody').on('click', '#addBtnGneral', function () {
            var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var id = data['id'];
            var url = "{{url('/create-general-sales/')}}/" + id;
            window.location.href = url;
        });

    })
```

Some one please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used same `table` variable, you should make them different to do some actions with them.

```
$(function () {
        var table1 = $('#example6').DataTable({
            'paging': true,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ url('/manage-order/data') }}",
                type: 'post'
            },

            "columns": [

                {"data": "vn_name"},
                {"data": "vn_id"},
                {"data": "total_payment_amount"},
                {"data": "total_due_ammont"},

                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<a id='addBtn' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' title='Add Purchase'>\n" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>\n" +
                    "</a>\n" 
                }
            ]
        });

        var table2 = $('#example5').DataTable({
            'paging': true,
            "serverSide": true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ url('/manage-general-sales/data') }}",
                type: 'post'
            },
            "columns": [

                {"data": "vendor_name"},
                {"data": "total_payment_amount"},
                {"data": "total_due_amount"},
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<a id='addBtnGneral' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' title='Add Purchase'>\n" +
                    "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>\n" +
                    "</a>\n" 
                }
            ]
        });
        $('#example6 tbody').on('click', '#addBtn', function () {
            var data = table1.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var vn_id = data['vn_id'];
            var url = "{{url('/create-order/')}}/" + vn_id;
            window.location.href = url;
        });


        $('#example5 tbody').on('click', '#addBtnGneral', function () {
            var data = table2.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var id = data['id'];
            var url = "{{url('/create-general-sales/')}}/" + id;
            window.location.href = url;
        });

    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DennisFrea